# Link Table A Column NAME with Table B data MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I am trying to link(join) the NAME column from PBXSTATION to the PBXDATA table. I also want it to be able to match the NAME with the EXT(extension) column?
EXTENSION in PBXSTATION is the same as EXT in PBXDATA. I will rename EXT to EXTENSION, that way the fields match. Any help would be great. My MSSQL Server is a little hazy. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT ps.*,
       pd.ext AS extension
       ....   --add other column names from pbxdata 
FROM PBXSTATION ps
JOIN PBXDATA pd ON ps.Name = pd.Name
                AND pd.Ext = ps.Extension
WHERE ps.Name = pd.Ext;
```

Comment: Do I list all the columns as so ID, CALL_TIME, CALL_TIME_UTC? Or do I have to use variables? like pd.ext AS extension

Comment: No, you can just list all columns just like pd.ext. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help.

Comment: Please feel free to mark this as accepted answer. As it helps other know that this has been resolved.